# Is Mathematica 10 compatible with Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: mac-os-x

When I try to launch Mathematica 10 on my iMac with OS X 10.10, I get the message:

> To open 'Mathematica' you need to install the legacy Java SE runtime.

However, a Mac version is not available on the Java legacy site so the answer seems to be no.

Comment: The same dialog box has a button that will take you to the download page: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

Comment: I am (also) using both OS X Yosemite 10.10 and Mathematica 10 right now.

Comment: I really LOVE (*not*) that apparently Apple has deemed it acceptable proper to *break* something that *was* working without my knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

I think that prompt should let you move directly to the download page (I've encountered it for some other third-party software), but if not you can download the Java SE Runtime Environment for OS X from [EDITED thanks to szabolcs]: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

But yes, *Mathematica* is compatible with OS X 10.10. I'm using it right now.

Comment: JavaForOSX2014-001.dmg worked a treat.Many thanks, programming_historian!